# RSS 2 specification for item attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, rss

Do attributes in an RSS feed have a character limit? I have looked at the [specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) and there is no mention of it. I am making a database table to hold the contents of an item and deciding on what length I should be setting for each column, this is what I have at the moment:

- title VARCHAR(255)
- description TEXT
- link VARCHAR(255)
- guid VARCHAR(255)
- pubDate DATETIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit for the size of the fields in the spec and besides that there is no real advantage of doing varchar(255) for the size of the columns. Why don't you just go with varchar(max)? Also for the GUID, depending on your db, there could be a more suitable data type.

Comment: Thanks, I am using MySQL - what data type would you recommend?